# How to calculate marginal profit and the price to maximize profits?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, economics

> Let demand be given by $$q=300-5P$$ and let the cost be given by $$c=30+ 6q$$ Calculate the marginal profit in terms of demand $q$ and find the price to maximize profits.

Would it be possible for me to calculate both from the functions?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please consider adding further context (with an [edit]) to your question: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Can you calculate the revenue as a function of $q$?  The profit is revenue minus cost, so that will give profit as a function of $q$/  Do you know the definition of marginal profit?

Comment: the marginal profit is profit when one more item is added/produced as far as i understand but not sure how i can solve revenue,...but maybe first the demand function needs to be modified to P = 60 - 0.2q ?? and then the profit is P = 60 - 0.2q - (30+6q). No?

Comment: $TR=PQ=(60-0.2Q)Q$, $\pi=TR-TC=(60-0.2Q)Q-(30+6Q)=-0.2Q^2+54Q-30$, $M\pi=\pi'=-0.4Q+54=0 \Rightarrow Q=135 \Rightarrow P=60-0.2\cdot 135=33$.

Comment: thank you for the comments. that means the marginal profit is 135 and the price to maximize profits is 33?